# Why does Firefox keep trying to download 7zip_14396_stf.exe and setup_tsv48ouvr.exe

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 7-zip, file-download

When I start Firefox for the first time, two files try to download, but their download fails. I have searched to find out what these files are. The "7zip" file is from safe downloads, and it looks like the second file has something to do with the wiseconvert toolbar. This is not part of several tabs when I shut down Firefox. How can I stop this from trying to install?

Comment: Most likely you are coming back to a session that has tabs on download pages.  Try closing any tabs you don't need

Comment: There are not multiple tabs, and we know a little more about the problem now. I've updated the OP.

Comment: This happen on every startup? Disable all addons and plugins. Check if problem solved. If don't then you should check whole PC for malware for example with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) or [another software](http://alternativeto.net/tag/malware-remover/?sort=likes).

Comment: Yes, @crazypotato It happens on every Firefox startup. We removed some of the addons and plugins, but did not disable all. I'll go try that next. Thanks for input.